# How to import random_id with keepers

Tags: terraform, infrastructure

I have the current config applied elsewhere:

```
resource "random_id" "certificate" {
  byte_length = 3
  prefix      = "my-cert-prefix-"

  keepers = {
    "domains": "api.domain.com"
  }
}
```

.. and now I need to import to the current state.

Running the "show" cmd, we can see something like:

```
resource "random_id" "certificate" {
    b64         = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH"
    b64_std     = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH"
    b64_url     = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH"
    byte_length = 3
    dec         = "my-cert-prefix-14519239"
    hex         = "my-cert-prefix-dd8bc7"
    id          = "3YvH"
    keepers     = {
        "domains" = "api.domain.com"
    }
    prefix      = "my-cert-prefix-"
}
```

the docs are saying to import running something like:

`terraform import module.XXX.random_id.certificate "my-cert-prefix-,3YvH"`

how can I add the "keepers" attribute to the current state ?

(edit: adding current plan after importing)

```
# module.XXXX.google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.service must be replaced
+/- resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "service" {
      ~ certificate_id            = 5697321803048287000 -> (known after apply)
      ~ creation_timestamp        = "2020-09-22T11:35:18.396-07:00" -> (known after apply)
      ~ expire_time               = "2020-12-21T09:42:04.000-08:00" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                        = "projects/XX/global/sslCertificates/XXXX-dd8bc7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name                      = "my-cert-prefix-dd8bc7" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        project                   = "XXXX"
      ~ self_link                 = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/sslCertificates/my-cert-prefix-dd8bc7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ subject_alternative_names = [
          - "api.domain.com",
          - "europe-west1-api.domain.com",
          - "us-east1-api.domain.com",
          - "us-west1-api.domain.com",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        type                      = "MANAGED"

        managed {
            domains = [
                "api.domain.com",
                "europe-west1-api.domain.com",
                "us-east1-api.domain.com",
                "us-west1-api.domain.com",
            ]
        }

      - timeouts {}
    }

# module.XXXX.random_id.certificate must be replaced
+/- resource "random_id" "certificate" {
      ~ b64         = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH" -> (known after apply)
      ~ b64_std     = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH" -> (known after apply)
      ~ b64_url     = "my-cert-prefix-3YvH" -> (known after apply)
        byte_length = 3
      ~ dec         = "my-cert-prefix-14519239" -> (known after apply)
      ~ hex         = "my-cert-prefix-dd8bc7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id          = "3YvH" -> (known after apply)
      + keepers     = {
          + "domains" = "api.domain.com"
        } # forces replacement
        prefix      = "my-cert-prefix-"
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify anything about the keepers when importing state, that's just config that tells Terraform when to rotate the randomness instead of keeping it the same. If you import it as you show in your question and then run a plan do you see a diff? If so can you edit that into your question please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the execution plan in the original question

Comment: In the meantime, I manually updated the new json state file; this can be seen as a "middle ground" solution for now, just adds the missing attribute: `"keepers": {  "domains": "api.domain.com" }`

Comment: From looking at how import is implemented for that resource type, it seems like manually editing the state is the only way in this case. `terraform import` isn't really designed to work with these in-state-only objects, so the `random` provider is only covering the basics.